# I can't change the body background-color through style.css

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve, custom-background

Using a child of Twenty Twelve, I've been adding color to all the major containers (#main, #content, #secondary, etc.) using

```
#arbitrary-id {
 background-color: #dedede;
}
```

This works for everything but body. I should be more clear: it changed the body background color until I messed with the background color in "Appearance -> Background". Now no matter what I try, I can't override that.

Looking in the HTML of the page and inside the `<head>` I see:

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
</style>
```

Naturally, I tried to change the color using that selector, but since it's generated internally, that trumps the external CSS.

I'm at a total loss for how to do this. How do I change the background color of the body using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to [remove support for the custom background color](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_support).

```
remove_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```

You will probably need to hook it to get it to run after the parent `functions.php`

```
function disable_bg_wpse_97248() {
    remove_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','disable_bg_wpse_97248',100)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. You are a gentleman and a scholar. I'm very new to all this so I appreciate the full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your functions.php for somehting like:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
    'default-color' => 'e6e6e6',
```

Remove it, then you can use your CSS to change the background color.